# Multiplying an $n\times n\times n$ tensor by a $n\times n$ matrix and get a $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: matrices, tensors

I just discovered hypermatrices (for tensor representation right ?) and I would like to understand their algebra. I can't find information on the internet. If you know good references please let me know. I am not a mathematician so a numerical point of view would be great.

I would like to me able to practically make a product between an $n\times n \times n$ hypermatrix and an $n\times n$ matrix which should give a $n\times n$ matrix just like an $n\times n$ matrix times a vector produce a vector. Does this product have general name for higher dimension ? We always call it the "matrix-vector product".

Thanks in advance for your time

EDIT : I'm still stuck with my product. I followed the direction of tensor contraction but for an $n\times n\times n$ tensor times a $n\times n$ matrix it gives a $n\times n\times n$ tensor and not a $n\times n$ matrix. I also discovered [n-mode products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953185/tensors-and-matrices-multiplication?rq=1) but they are equivalent and give a $n\times n\times n$ tensor as a result.

Do you have other ideas for a product giving a **matrix** as a result ?

Comment: There is no "default" way to multiply a $3$-dimensional array with a $2$-dimensional array. However, the operations which are analogous to matrix-multiplication in this context are called [tensor contractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction).

Comment: Are you discovering this from a `numpy` or `torch` standpoint? In which case, you can just try to multiply some of these matrices in `python`. (Apologies if I assumed incorrectly) In general, you have to specify which dimension you want to “keep”, because there are at least 3 ways to do the multiplication you said.

Comment: I'm not discovering this from Python but from a proposed (but not explicited) algorithm in physics. Thanks for the name "tensor contraction", it helps. Sorry I'm not familiar with tensors but I will investigate in this direction. If possible, could you post an example of one of the 3 possible products you mentioned ? Either as a pseudo code or as an example with a 3x3x3 tensor times a 3x3 matrix ? It could really help me to dive into the topic.

Comment: I've never heard the term "hypermatrix" before. Is it a $(0,3)$ tensor? A $(2,1)$? More details please.

Comment: It seems that hypermatrices are the coordinate representation of tensors in the same way that matrices are the coordinate representation of linear operators.

Comment: @kipgon I've been asking myself the same question for years, and actually, my conclusion is that it's a bit more complex than that. (Column) Vectors are $v^i$ tensors, covectors (row vectors) are $v_i$ tensors. Linear maps are $T^i_j$ tensors, and correspond to your usual matrices. Symmetric matrices/metric tensors are $G_{ij}$ tensors and CAN be represented as square matrices, if you do a $v^T Gw$ product. But it's "closer to the algebra" to see $G_{ij}$ as a "row vector of row vectors", and applying first $v$ to each "coordinate row vector", then $w$ to the "row vector of first results".